# Не работает ввод параметра из файла в командной строке linux

Tags: c++, linux

Есть задача: нужно написать программу в vscode,которая выводит на стандартный поток текст `"Hello, Name"`, где `Name` – введённое имя при запуске из командной строки или терминала. То есть запрос в командной строке выглядит примерно так:

```
./"имя программы" Ivan
Hello,Iva
./"имя программы" >out.txt <in.txt - // ничего в out не падает ( в in.txt конечно лежит имя )
```

КОД VS CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    using namespace std;
    int num;
    if (argc > 1) {
        if (argc == 3) {
            cout << "Выберите номер используемого параметра\n";
            cin >> num;
            if (num == 1) {
                cout << "Hello," << argv[1];
            }
            else
                cout << "Hello," << argv[2];
        }
        else
            cout << "Hello," << argv[1];
    }
    else {
        ofstream file;
        file.open("error.txt");
        file << "Ошибка";
        file.close();
    }
        
 }
```

Уже не знаю что делать, буду очень благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 2):

```
< in.txt
```

это не передача параметра командной строки, а подмена содержимым файла стандартного ввода.

Так что при

```
./"имя программы" >out.txt <in.txt
```

`argc==1` и вы должны получить файл `error.txt`...

Действуйте так - если `argc==1`, т.е. аргументов командной строки нет (а перенаправление ввода-вывода таковыми не считается) - читайте имя из `cin`. Если я верно понял, что вы хотите. Если нет - задайте вопрос понятнее..

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Объясните пожалуйста, почему подмена содержимым из файла не является аргументом. То есть я же ввожу имя с клавиатуры, и в файле лежит тоже самое имя, введенное с клавиатуры, и оно считывается.

Comment: Аргумент командной строки - это то, что написано в командной строке после имени выполнимого файла, а не то, что вы вводите с клавиатуры. А с вашим "уточнением"- "*я же ввожу имя с клавиатуры, и в файле лежит тоже самое имя, введенное с клавиатуры, и оно считывается*" - я теперь вообще не понимаю, в чем у вас проблема, и что вы хотите...